# Castor: how to map a simple list of strings?

Tags: java, xml, castor

I have the following field in my class:

```
private List<String> messages;
```

Here's the mapping I have:

```
<field name="messages" collection="arraylist" type="string" container="false>
  <bind-xml name="errors" node="element"/>
</field>
```

This is what I get as a result of marshalling:

```
<errors><string>message1</string><string>message2</string></errors>
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

```
<errors><error>message1</error><error>message2</error></errors>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you are using Marshalling to achieve this?  It will have a set way of defining the XML output so that it knows how to recreate the objects when unmarshalling.  So if you really want that XML output using marshalling I think you would need to create a new type called Error and your list would be:

```
private List<Error> messages;
```

And the mapping:

```
<field name="messages" collection="arraylist" type="error" container="false>
  <bind-xml name="errors" node="element"/>
</field>
```

Alternatively, if you are just looking to create xml output and your content really is as simple as what you have given above then you could just write a toXml() method which loops through the list adding the content exactly as you want it.  The inverse can be done with a fromXml() method that parses the XML using DOM or SAX and rebuilds the list of strings.

Comment: Thank you, Dave, for confirming my findings that what I want can't be done with Castor. In our project we use Castor to render XML views (domain object -> XML). Usually our content is not as simple, I was just adding a mapping for an object that carried error messages which are presented to the user.

I still can't believe something this simple cannot be done!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JAXB?

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Errors {

        private List<String> messages;

        @XmlElement(name="error")
        public List<String> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }

        public void setMessages(List<String> messages) {
            this.messages = messages;
        }

    }
```

If you like an external binding file you can use [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Errors">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="messages" name="error"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but you might want to consider using `container="true"`.

Comment: any recommendations why using it?

Comment: The Castor documentation does a much better job of explaining what the container attribute does.  See Table 1.10 of [the Castor data binding document](https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guides/1.3.3/html/XML%20data%20binding.html) for more info.  Generally speaking, any time you use a collection class to store a bunch of objects, you don't want Castor to persist the collection class per se, just the things stored inside it.  The XML produced is a bit cleaner. IMHO.